# Correct usage of lambda functions with Pycodestyle

Tags: python, lambda, pycodestyle

I have working code with a `lambda` function. And it is working fine but pycodestyle informs me to no assign my `lambda` function to a variable. Instead I should use `def` to create the function. I totally understand why I should not do this, because of debugging process with millions of lambda functions as reference. Is there a way to use `lambda` correctly with a flake8 ruleset or are they not allowed completly for the reasons mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend you to ignore such warning. In case you really want to do that, you can just configure Flake8 to ignore the rule [E731](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E731.html).

Add this to your [project's configuration file](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/2.5.5/config.html#per-project):

```
[flake8]
ignore = E731
```

Lambdas in general are allowed. What flake8 recommends against is assigning a name to a lambda (anonymous) function.

Comment: So I would just ignore this rule. I generly aksed for: Are in some other way lambda functions allowed with pycodestyle? Just mentioning: The original code ignores flake8 in too many rules. I can absolutly live without lambda functions ;)

Comment: They are allowed, as long as you don't assign a name to them. You can pass them directly as parameters to functions, for example and flake8 won't complain about that.

Comment: If you add this to your awnser I will except it **thumbsup**

Comment: I actually used it and I am pretty happy about it.